# WHERE CLAUSE is not filtering results

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this working function in my model where I'm trying to get the position of students in a class based on their subject scores.

This is working but the where clause does not filter results to classify them based on subjects.

model:

```
public function GetSubjectPosScores($exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id) 
    {
        $sql = "SELECT `get_tot_score` FROM `exam_group_exam_results` 
WHERE `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id`= `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id` ORDER BY `get_tot_score` DESC";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
    }
```

controller:

```
public function GetSubjectPosScores($exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id)
    {
        $data = $this->examresult_model->GetSubjectPosScores($exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id); 
        return $data;
    }
```

view:

```
<?php
$scores2 = $CI->GetSubjectPosScores($exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id); //echo $value->pos;
$scores = array_column($scores2, 'get_tot_score');
$pos = array_search($exam_result_value->get_tot_score, $scores);
$number = $pos + 1;
 echo $CI->ordinal($number);?>
```

This is what I get with this query:

```
student_id | subject_id | get_tot_score | Position
---------------------------------------------------
 11        |   1        |   76          |  3rd
 12        |   1        |   90          |  1st
 28        |   6        |   89          |  2nd
 30        |   6        |   70          |  4th
```

what I want is this :

```
student_id | subject_id | get_tot_score | Position
---------------------------------------------------
 11        |   1        |   76          |  2nd
 12        |   1        |   90          |  1st
 28        |   6        |   89          |  1st
 30        |   6        |   70          |  2nd
```

Comment: I think issue with the where clause it sould be```"WHERE `subject_id`= '{$exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id}'"```.  And further if you need Position you can use loops and recreate the array, `if $get_tot_score > 80 is 1st, if $get_tot_score >= 70 && $get_tot_score < 80 is is 2nd` etc..

Comment: yes, figured it out. I should have done this in my view   ```$scores2 = $CI->GetSubjectPosScores($exam_result_value->id); ```  instead of this ```$scores2 = $CI->GetSubjectPosScores($exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id); ```

Answer (score 2):

the problem is in your query

```
SELECT `get_tot_score` FROM `exam_group_exam_results` 
WHERE `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id`= `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id` ORDER BY `get_tot_score` DESC
```

basically your are checking that the value in the column`exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id`
is equal to the value of the column  `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id`

Which is always true

you have to change it passing your value `$exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id` using some sort of statement (I don't know what library you are using)

**edit**
I take a look at codignirer documentation

just try this

```
public function GetSubjectPosScores($exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id) 
    {
        $sql = "SELECT `get_tot_score` FROM `exam_group_exam_results` 
WHERE `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id`= ? ORDER BY `get_tot_score` DESC";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql, [$exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id]);
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean library? I'm new to all these. I use CodeIgniter

Comment: it didn't work as everyone is now carrying the 1st position

Answer (score 0):

You have specified string value in the where condition and not the value of the variable passed as parameter in the getSubjectPosScores function

Use [String Interpolation](https://riptutorial.com/php/example/22788/string-interpolation) in your query

Replace

> `public function GetSubjectPosScores($exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id)  { $sql = "SELECT` get_tot_score`FROM`exam_group_exam_results`WHERE`exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id`=` exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id`ORDER BY`get_tot_score `DESC"; $query = $this->db->query($sql); return $query->result(); }`

with this

> `public function GetSubjectPosScores($exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id)  { $sql = "SELECT get_tot_score FROM exam_group_exam_results WHERE exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id= $exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id ORDER BY get_tot_score DESC"; $query = $this->db->query($sql); return $query->result(); }`

Or

> `public function GetSubjectPosScores($exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id)  { $sql = "SELECT` get_tot_score`FROM`exam_group_exam_results`WHERE`exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id`= '".$exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id."' ORDER BY` get_tot_score `DESC"; $query = $this->db->query($sql); return $query->result(); }`